# How do I generate normally distributed variables and then plot Students' distribution for it using $dt()$ function in R?

Tags: r

So, I need to simply plot Student's distribution with a corresponding coefficient of freedoms and along with it draw a normally distributed line.

I came up with awfully clumsy code:

```
    x <- rnorm(20, mean = 0, sd = 1)
y <- replicate(30, x)
plot(dt(y, 2), type = "l")
```

which gives me a line, not a curve. I am not sure, whether I need to replicate the $x$ as I should be able to draw density function for it and it should be like a bell curve, because the numbers are generated from normal distribution?

When I tried this code:

```
x <- replicate(30, mean(rnorm(20, mean = 0, sd = 1)))
plot(density(x))
```

it gave me something similar to bell curve, but very uneven and not like a density function at all. When I plotted simply x, for some reason it took means of generated samples as y axis and x axis was just index numbers. Can anyone help? I need to draw Students' distribution for normally distributed data, but I am even unable to plot density curve for normally distributed variables. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Does this help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267540/plotting-the-student-t-probability-density-r

Comment: @Edward Yes, thank you.